# What is the flow of attachment upload in mail?

Tags: email, file-upload

I want to know how  "attach a file"  during sending mail works??
When user choose a file to be send ,then  a progress bar is shown.
Where the choose file is stored at that moment in the client browser or  uploaded  to the server side.
After clicking send Is that file  transfered to the receiver mail or the link to the file is send?
Please  can someone make me clear about the whole concept so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular file upload inputs are without progress indications. These send the file on submit of the form.

When you have an upload indication this suggests that the file is 'pre' uploaded to the server of your mail hosting before the actual e-mail is send. On sending the e-mail the uploaded file link will be send to the server and the actual file will be attached in their system.